# Naming parents and children in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm looking to change the respective names the properties of parents and children in my LINQ to SQL data model. Check out this area of my ERD:

[image: Relationship between Users and Transactions]

From Users to Transactions I have to foreign keys:

- Users.UserId -> Transactions.SenderId
- Users.UserId -> Transactions.ReceiverId

When I work with these relationships, they are named confusingly. For that reason I decided to change the respective names of these properties. I did this in the LINQ to SQL designer:

[image: Properties of a relationship]

In the above example I changed the name of the child to `TransactionsBySender` and the name of the parent to `Sender`. This worked out perfectly and, now, I'm able to take advantage of the benefits provided by LINQ. My problem is that these name changes are overwritten everytime I update my data model.

My question therefore is: Can I do these name changes directly in SQL Server using Management Studio?

Comment: If you are regularly updating your model from the database, consider using the Hugati tools (http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/) or PLinqo (http://www.codesmithtools.com/plinqo). Alternativly, consider manually making the changes on both sides rather than dropping and recreating the entities with each schema change.

Answer (score 0):

Not in SQL Server management studio.

You can use a partial class and do it there, this is a similar approach where I have to references to tb_bestand what comes in the dbml as tb_bestand and tb_bestand1. This way I rename tb_bestand1 to a more logical name:

```
public partial class ...
{

    public tb_bestand tb_morelogicalname
    {
        get
        {
            return this._tb_bestand1.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tb_bestand1 = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You can rename the relational constraints (the Foreign KEY constraints) on the property editor of the SQL Server Management Studio.

On the table name of the left side panel, simply right click table name and choose Design.., then click Relationships button on the toolbar.
This will display the available relational constraints of the table you design/edit.

Additional notes: it seems you want the name on the SQL Server Management Studio table Designer to be the same on the code. You can't do this directly.